# Make the Drawer open when switching to small screen

Tags: javascript, material-design-lite

I trying to use Material Design Lite and made a small interface. And now I face with a problem - I need to make the Drawer always open, when window loads and when window goes from large screen to small.
By default, the Drawer always starts with close state...

I found that some changes comes, when I hit Drawer button (pink color on screenshot).

I tried to use QuerySelector like that:

```
var obfuscator = document.querySelector('.mdl-layout__obfuscator');
obfuscator.className = 'mdl-layout__obfuscator is-visible'
```

but it cant detect that element... Can someone gimme better way to do such simple task?)) I really stacked with it...

[image]

Comment: You can detect for window onload & resize events and trigger open the drawer as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536467/how-to-hide-drawer-upon-user-click

Comment: thx, finally got how to make it work...:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on link, that Cody gave in the comment, I got that.

```
    window.onload = function() {
        var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0)
        if (w <= 1000) {
            document.querySelector('.mdl-layout__obfuscator').classList.add('is-visible');
            document.querySelector('.mdl-layout__drawer').classList.add('is-visible');
        };
    };
```

So now Drawer start opened when screen size below or equal 1000px. My first mistake was that I missed that `material.js` loads up with `defer` and because of that I cant find `mdl-layout__obfuscator` and `mdl-layout__drawer`. Like always, stupid mistakes made pain in... u know that place :)